# How do I use Bootstrap's input-append style search field style with Joomla 3?

Tags: search, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I'm building a site in Joomla 3 with Bootstrap. The built-in search module gives you a search field with a submit button next it; how can I change it to the "input-append" style where the submit button is appended to the search field?

Comment: Create a template override and restructure as needed. http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Customise_the_Module_Output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my code of `/templates/[mytemplate]/html/mod_search/default.php`:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php');?>" method="post" class="form-inline search<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx ?>">
    <label class="element-invisible"><?php echo $label ?></label>
    <div class="input-append">
        <input name="searchword" maxlength="<?php echo $maxlength ?>" class="inputbox<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx ?>  input-medium" type="text" size="<?php echo $width ?>" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $text ?>" />
        <button type="submit" class="button<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx ?> btn"><?php echo $text?></button>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_search" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="<?php echo $mitemid; ?>" />
</form>
```

Some module options won't work like position of search button and so on.
I also added native placeholder instead of javascript function that didn't work anyway.